# C'è una differenza tra concretare e concretizzare?

Tags: difference, synonym

Su Treccani trovo l'[uno](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/concretare/) e l'[altro](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/concretizzare) verbo, ma il secondo rimanda al primo

> **concretiżżare** v. tr. [der. di *concreto*]. – Lo stesso, e oggi forma più com., che *concretare*.

Mi chiedevo se c'è una sfumatura di significato.

Comment: Secondo quanto si può vedere da Google Books, concretare è ora meno comune di concretizzare, soprattutto dagli anni 80. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concretare%2Cconcretizzare%2C+concretarsi&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconcretare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcretizzare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcretarsi%3B%2Cc0 - forse è da chiedersi come mai sia stato “rimpiazzato” da concretizzare.

Comment: Per quanto riguarda il significato, mi sembra sia identico a quello di concretizzare: https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/concretare.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oltre che il Treccani, anche il [De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/concretare) e il [Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana](http://www.gdli.it/sala-lettura/vol/3?seq=494) li danno come equivalenti, il primo rinviando da “concretare” a “concretizzare”, il secondo viceversa (e con la divertente osservazione del Tommaseo secondo cui quest'ultimo è “è inutile, e ancora più inelegante di ‘concretare’”). Tenderei a fidarmi.

Aggiungerei soltanto che il fatto che “concretizzare” è oggi più comune di “concretare” (come menziona il Treccani e come conferma [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concretare%2Cconcretizzare&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=33&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconcretare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcretizzare%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconcretare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcretizzare%3B%2Cc0): grazie @Hachi), di per sé, conferisce una lieve sfumatura alla scelta di uno dei due: il lettore può percepire la preferenza per una parola più o meno ricercata.

Comment: Aggiungerei che oggi "*concretare*" è usato, credo, solo in forma riflessiva. "Tutti i suoi studi e tutto il suo lavoro si concretarono in..." è poco comune ma si può sentire/leggere mentre non credo di aver mai sentito "concretò tutti i suoi studi e tutto il suo lavoro in..."

Answer (score 4):

In aggiunta a quanto riportato nella risposta di DaG, aggiungo quanto ho trovato nel Devoto-Oli, *Nuovo Vocabolario Illustrato della Lingua Italiana* (per intenderci, [questo](https://pictures.abebooks.com/isbn/9788870450811-it-300.jpg)):

> **concretare** v. tr. (*concrèto*, ecc.) Attuare, realizzare, rendere efficiente e operante sul piano pratico: *c. un disegno, un progetto, un piano* ◆ ***rifl.*** Precisarsi, definirsi, assumere consistenza ed efficienza. [Der. di *concreto*].

> **concretizzare**  ⟨-ẓẓ-⟩ v. tr. Meno comune di *concretare*.

Evidentemente è un po' vecchiotto (nelle prima pagine leggo *©1967-1987* e *Prima Edizione: Agosto 1987*), ma sembra essere quantomento compatibile con l'osservazione di Tommaseo riportata da DaG.

Comment: Grazie, è ottimo avere una fonte in più, ed è interessante che all'epoca “concretizzare” fosse meno comune di “concretare”. Puoi aggiungere di che anno è l'edizione da cui citi? Potresti anche aggiungere per chiarezza che si tratta del Devoto-Oli.

Comment: @DaG, non so come ho fatto a dimenticare il nome degli autori, anche perché conoscevo il vocabolario proprio come "Devoto-Oli" e non come "Vocabolario ...". Per quanto riguarda la data, il vocabolario illustrato in due volumi è del '67. Non so però come funziona la storia di ristampe/correzione/ecc per i vocabolari. Controllo appena possible.

Comment: Effettivamente uno “stesso” dizionario, nel corso dei decenni e delle successive edizioni, può cambiare notevolmente. Credo che lo Zingarelli attuale non contenga niente di quello che scrisse Nicola Zingarelli ottant'anni fa, e idem per le varie edizioni del Devoto-Oli, che attualmente mantiene il nome ma è redatto da Serianni e Trifone. (segue)

Comment: Per questo è importante segnalare la data dell'edizione che si cita, non per sminuire il valore della citazione, ma per inquadrarla storicamente. Io, per esempio, sono geloso di un mio Zingarelli del 1948 che trovai su una bancarella, prezioso come fotografia della lingua italiana in quel momento. Tornando a noi, l'edizione che citi è appunto del 1987; il 1967 è l'anno di pubblicazione del primo _Vocabolario illustrato della lingua italiana_ di Devoto e Oli.